# Restricting an untrusted computer on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Basically I have my own personal network where I share some resources between my computers.

A family member wants to join his PC wirelessly to my network (I can't say no). The problem is I don't him to be able to access any of my files, not get my computers infected with viruses through his computer or something.

Any idea how I can protect my network? I use a Cisco WAG160N router btw.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linksys-Cisco WAG160N has a built-in firewall feature (based on the user [manual](http://downloads.linksysbycisco.com/downloads/userguide/1224645029534/WAG120N-160Nv2-320N-EMEA_UG_C-WEB.pdf)).

You can try fiddling with the features there to allow your family member to only access the internet but not other parts of your network.